# Looking for Bipolar Disorder treatment method

Tags: depression, psychiatrist-psychiatry, audiology, bipolar-disorder

My brother and me are ill with [Bipolar Affective disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_disorder). My brother's illness is in the **severe stage**, and we have no idea what to do, medications do not provide improvement. I hope that [audio-psycho-phonology](http://www.tomatis-center.gr/en/the-tomatis-method/audio-psycho-phonology/) should help, I have felt its effects on myself and I trust in it. Also I understand in detail  how it works. We have tried several [Tomatis audio](http://www.tomatis.com/en/tomatis-method/a-listening-program.html) courses (playlists) in Russia, but the result is not so good. Now I want to find the best place in the world for Tomatis listening. What Tomatis center do you recommend, where are the the best experts and the most high-tech equipment? As far as I know, the last Tomatis technology is based on **3-channels heaphones**, not on 2, and also can provide a **real-time** voice processing. And what else [Tomatis-based (audio-psycho-phonology) methods](http://www.thelisteningcenter.net/compare.php) can you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Since Bipolar disorder is a medical condition you and your brother should find a psychiatrist who can manage your pathology optimally.

Even if you trust in this audio-psycho-phonology it is not supported by any scientific evidence so I would advice against using it.

Medical therapy (lithium etc) is essential and could be eventually supported by phycotherapy.

As a side note I would add that Tomatis method has only been indagated in a case-control study on autism and [has been proven of none efficacy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17610057).

Comment: 1. No one psychiatrist can manage our pathology optimally. 2. Alfred Tomatis was a physician and a scientist. 3. Medical therapy (lithium etc) has almost no influence for my brother. Also we both have little influence of mood stabilizers (which usually is the basis of treatment of bipolar disorder). 4. **The Tomatis method is absolutely the best treatment method for autism.** 5. But our illness is not autism, and now we unfortunately really have not good treatment options

Comment: 1. How can you be sure? 2. Right he graduated in Medicine, but he is not allowed to practice anymore since his methods are not recognized by science. 3. Sad to hear that. 4. This is absolutely not true. Please provide link to evidence. 5. Both autism and bipolar disorder have good treatment options, Tomatis method is not one of them.

Comment: what can you suggest?

Comment: I would find a good psychiatrist.

Comment: +1 especially for the first paragraph, *find a psychiatrist*